# Errors when booting with encrypted LVM

Tags: lvm, encryption

When I boot my computer and I have to enter the password of the encrypted lvm, there are always a bunch of annyoing messages like:
"usb string descriptor 0 read error: -22". How can I fix that?

my hooks are:

> HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block filesystems keyboard keymap
>   encrypt lvm2 fsck"

Btw: This is cosmetic, it boots and works fine!

Answer (score 0):

The order seems a bit weird to me, no idea if this matters.
Try this order:

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect modconf block keymap keyboard encrypt lvm2 filesystems fsck"
```

Comment: I changed it like you said and ran a mkinitcpio -p linux but still the same